# Cancel event using ical file

Tags: icalendar

I know there are many similar questions but for some reason the ical to cancel an event stopped working both on Gmail and Outlook. The latter returns always "non supported calendar message.ics"

My ics file looks like:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:MYPORD
METHOD:CANCEL
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Meeting Cancellation
DTSTART:20190726T083500Z
DTEND:20190726T093500Z
DTSTAMP:20190726T091329Z
UID:meeting-944
ATTENDEE:mailto:my@email.com
ORGANIZER:mailto:organiser@email.com
STATUS:CANCELLED
SEQUENCE:1
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I checked on Outlook documentation, but I only found some issues with RRULE field, which is not the case here.

Any ideas?

**Edit**: Added the organiser field too. Still not working...

Answer (score 3):

Two possible reasons:

Are your lines terminated by CRLF or just LF ? Should be CRLF. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.1

You are missing the ORGANIZER property which is mandatory for a CANCEL message as per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-3.2.5

Finally, your DTSTAMP should be later than the DTSTAMP of the original invite.

Comment: I added the organiser field too. You can see how my ics file looks now. I am using a Python library to generate the ical which works fine for all methods apart from CANCEL. Tried to convert to CRLF, but still not working

Comment: your DTSTAMP looks suspicious as well. Does it reflect the current time when sending the CANCEL ?

Comment: yes, it gets the current time when the ical is generated

Comment: @ArnaudQuillaud, thumbs up for the DTSTAMP